# Fedora 17 guest in Vmware WS 8 on WIndows 7 - Slow graphics

Tags: windows-7, fedora, vmware-workstation

I have installed Fedora 17 as a guest in Vmware workstation 8 (8.0.5 build-893925) on a Windows 7 64 bit host. I have installed vmware tools and rebooted. However the display is painfully slow. Have I missed a step, or is there something I can do to improve the experience.

For completeness, this is running on a HP6730b laptop with 8gb ram, with an intel core 2 duo P8600 @ 2.4ghz

Output from guest of uname -a:

`Linux development 3.6.8-2.fc17.i686 #1 SMP Tue Nov 27 20:14:11 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I've switched desktop to xfce which isn't perfect, but is usable.